# How do I set a Private boolean variable to true/false from a static function?

Tags: java

I have declared a (global) private boolean variable `isLocked` and I need to set it to `true` or `false` from a static function without violating the static rule. How can I do that?

```
if (verAccount != null && verAccount.nSequentialFailedAuthenticationAttempts==3) {
    System.out.println("YOUR ACCOUNT IS LOCKED :(");
    isLocked.equals(true);
}`
```

Comment: From static method you can only access static class members. So unless your boolean variable is static there's no way to do what you want.

Comment: makw `isLocked` as instance veriable associated with every objeect.